# How to switch embed element type from PDF stream to text stream

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, pdf, embed

In my JSP web application I am using the `embed` element to display a PDF.

```
<embed src="someurl" width="900">
```

The `someurl` will return a PDF stream in one case and a text stream in another case:

```
if (IamPDF) {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    /* rest of stream flushing */
} else {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    /* rest of stream flushing */
}
```

I can flush the PDF stream without problem in both IE and Chrome. In case of a text stream, IE is unable to display the stream, but it’s working in Chrome. And I did not specify any type in the `embed` element. How to make it work in IE?

Comment: If they’re not the cause of the problem, they’re just noise in the question. You increase the value of your question (and chances of getting upvotes and answers) when you remove the noise. You should [edit] in such cases, and moreover you should post the original code (not retype it; just delete irrelevant parts). I did the edit for you now.

Comment: Did the answer help you solve your problem? If so, you should upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this by setting the [`type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-embed-type) attribute of the [`embed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-embed-element) element.

For HTML

```
<embed src="someurl" type="text/html" width="900">
```

and for PDF

```
<embed src="someurl" type="application/pdf" width="900">
```

Quoting [the `embed` element specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-embed-element):

> The [`type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-embed-type) attribute, if present, gives the MIME type by which the plugin to instantiate is selected. The value must be a valid MIME type. If both the `type` attribute and the `src` attribute are present, then the `type` attribute must specify the same type as the explicit [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#content-type) metadata of the resource given by the `src` attribute.

<sup>Links to MIME type and valid MIME type removed, they’re irrelevant.</sup>

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer, Content-Type of the stream varies some times it comes as `Text Stream (html/text)` and sometimes `application/pdf` the problem here is when I set `type` attribute in `embed` tag to `html/text` it will only render the `Text stream` and it gives error for `application/pdf` and the same vice versa.. so my Problem is how to set `type` attribute in dynamic way..

Comment: In Dynamic way do you intend server or Client side? if Serverside you could use (type="<%= isPdf ? "application/pdf" : "text/html">") something like that, if client side I think you must use javascript.

Comment: Yeah I tried that way as well.. The problem here is that `<embed>` tag is not caring of what server returns.. Its taking from the `type` attribute. .. which we cant change dynamically..

Answer (score 0):

Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the first line of your JSP to make IE render webpages in standard mode.
For example, 

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<embed src="someurl" width="900">`

Answer (score 0):

I would specify the type attribute in the

```
<embed></embed>
```

tag; I also have had problems with internet explorer not accepting certain functions and such in Javascript. It's just not a good browser. I prefer Chrome or Firefox, and I know a few people who swear by Opera.